# How to create a tibble with one column and column name from a vector?

Tags: r, vector, tidyverse, tibble

I tried to do it but it creates a tibble with two columns.:

```
>vect<-c(1,2,3)
> enframe(vect1, name="var")
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    var value
  <int> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     2     2
3     3     3
```

I need to create tibble like this:

```
    var 
  <int> 
       1    
       2    
       3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `select` after the `enframe` (if the `enframe` is already done)

```
library(tidyverse)
enframe(vect, name="var") %>%
       select(var)
```

---

Or just use `tibble`

```
tibble(var = vect)
# A tibble: 3 x 1
#    var
#  <dbl>
#1     1
#2     2
#3     3
```